# REST error-The request contain entity body but no Content-Type header.The infered media type application/octet-stream is not support for this resource

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, postman

I'm trying to send POST request.
While sending via POSTMAN all goes well, then I try to send it by C# code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

var client = new RestClient(MY-URL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ServerUsername, Password);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("undefined", My JSON Data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I'm getting this error:

> The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not supported for this resource

How can I solve it?

Comment: are you sending raw JSON or are you serializing an object model to send? If the latter, replace `request.AddParameter` with `request.AddJsonBody(model)`

Comment: Otherwise you need to include type when adding the parameter ie `request.AddParameter("application/json", My JSON Data, ParameterType.RequestBody);`

Comment: Did you ever found the answer ? I have the exact same problem

Answer (score 4):

Try to write:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

Or add to your header:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a parameter as body changes the content type of the request.

In your example

```
request.AddParameter("undefined", My JSON Data, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

overrides the content type previously set.

If are you serializing an object model to send, then replace `request.AddParameter` with

```
request.AddJsonBody(model);
```

which will serialize and include the appropriate header information

Otherwise you need to include type when adding the parameter

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "My JSON Data", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution for me- request.AddParameter("application/json", "My JSON Data", ParameterType.RequestBody);

Comment: @user7768692 if this resolved the problem, remember to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Actually it works in my other project . This line "request.AddParameter("application/json", "My JSON Data", ParameterType.RequestBody);" already in my code. but no luck.

Comment: The only difference , I updated My RestSharp Libray to "106.11.4"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using Fiddler and somehow I had an extra carriage return that I could not see within Fiddler.

Fiddler SHOWED this in my scratch pad:

```
POST https://mywebsite/?api-version=7.3 HTTP/1.1
AnotherHeader: 2413OL
```

But after pasting into Nodepad I saw this:

```
POST https://mywebsite/?api-version=7.3 HTTP/1.1

AnotherHeader: 2413OL
```

After removing the extra carriage return in Notepad and then pasting back into Fiddler's scratch pad, all is well and the 415 status code is gone.