# The request contain entity body but no Content-Type header.The inferred media type application/octet-stream is not support for this resource

Tags: c#, restsharp

I already read this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53515565/rest-error-the-request-contain-entity-body-but-no-content-type-header-the-infere/53516134) but no luck.

I'm using RestShap v106.11.4.

```
public async static Task<ApiResponseBase<T>> ExecuteApiRequestAsync<T>(ApiRequestParameter parameter) where T : new()
{
        RestClient client = new RestClient(parameter.ApiBaseUrl);
        client.UseNewtonsoftJson();

        Method reqMethod = (Method)Enum.Parse(typeof(Method), parameter.HttpMethod.ToUpper());
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(parameter.Resource, reqMethod);
        //request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json"); // Also tried this too.No luck.

        if (parameter.RequireToken)
        {
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"bearer {parameter.BearerToken}");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.Body))
        {
            //request.AddJsonBody(parameter.Body);
            request.AddParameter("application/json", parameter.Body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        }

        if ((reqMethod == Method.POST || reqMethod == Method.PUT)
                && (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.FileName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameter.FilePath)))
        {
            request.AddFile(parameter.FileName, parameter.FileName);
        }

        IRestResponse<ApiResponseBase<T>> response = await client.ExecuteAsync<ApiResponseBase<T>>(request);

        return response.Data;
}
```

I got an `UnSupportedMediaType` error if I change my API's verb from `POST` to `GET`. The API is working perfectly in Postman.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Restsharp Documnetation](https://restsharp.dev/usage/parameters.html#request-body)

> RequestBody does not work on GET or HEAD Requests, as they do not send a body.